# @Valid annotation not being verified through Junit Quarkus

Tags: java, junit5, quarkus

I'm working with Quarkus and facing weird scenario where @Valid annotation not working as expected in JUnit but working fine in REST API.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Test**

```
@Test
  void
      validateContent_GivenInvalidFieldName_ThrowConstraintViolationException() {
    // Arrange
    String invalidFieldName =
        "{\"i\": \"Test\"}";
    
    // Act, Assert
    assertThrows(
        ConstraintViolationException.class,
        () -> service.validate(invalidFieldName),
        "ConstraintViolationException exception should be thrown");
  }
```

**Service class method**

```
public void validate(String jsonString){
try {
      ValidField validField = convert(jsonString);
      validateContent(validField);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      createValidationError(e.getMessage(), "content");
    }
}

void validateContent(
      @Valid ValidField content) {
    //  @Valid doing the work here
  }
```

**Model class**

```
public class ValidField{
private String id;

  @NotBlank
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: why is this unexpected? you do know that you need to have a validator for Valid annotation to work? Valid annotation does not do anything by itself, it is just a signpost to a configured validator that something should be validated.

Comment: Through REST its working as expected, Means Validator must be there.

Comment: This dependency is added already <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

The @Valid annotation does not do anything by itself, it's just a "metadata" instructing an validator implementation to validate the entity. In your rest endpoint is working because it's a bean managed by quarkus, and the framework will automatically weave the validator for you. This will not happen in a plain junit test. The easiest way to make it work in your case, is to turn the validator into a bean and create a test using the QuarkusTest, like this:

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class YourValidatorService() {
    
        public void validate(String jsonString) {
            try {
                ValidField validField = convert(jsonString);
                validateContent(validField);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                createValidationError(e.getMessage(), "content");
            }
        }
    
        void validateContent(
            @Valid ValidField content) {
            //  @Valid doing the work here
        }
    
    }
```

and injecting into your test using the @QuarkusTest annotation

```
@QUarkusTest
public class YourValidatorServiceTest() {

    @Inject
    private YourValidatorService service;

    @Test
    void validateContent_GivenInvalidFieldName_ThrowConstraintViolationException() {
        // Arrange
        String invalidFieldName =
            "{\"i\": \"Test\"}";

        // Act, Assert
        assertThrows(
            ConstraintViolationException.class,
            () - > service.validate(invalidFieldName),
            "ConstraintViolationException exception should be thrown");
    }

}
```

By doing that, you will enable the Quarkus CDI on tests, which will weave the validator for you.

You can read a little bit more about how the validations work, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation).